# JSON Web Token usage and security

Tags: javascript, json, web, token, jwt

I'm going to use the JWT in my project for authentification. But during implementation I faced with some problem that I didn't resolve by reading a lot of documentation.

1. After getting the token I need to store it locally. I can use cookie but I'm not sure that it will securely. It is easy to open dev tool in browser, take a token and use independently from account owner. What's the best way to store it?
2. I got the token again. It has information about my account and my permissions. But after that I changed the password and my permissions were changed. And my token hasn't expired yet and I still has access with my old data. I can compare its data with data in data source but I'm not sure that it is good for perfomance. How to fix it?
3. This question is the similar with the second one. I found suspicious activity with my account so I want to drop all the tokens. How can I do it?

Comment: I just save the user id in the token and get the permissions from the DB, I store it in the localStorage to prevent CSRF attacks (Read this: https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage). BTW - It's recommended to pass the token over a secured connection (HTTPS)

Comment: @AlonEitan thanks for the answer. But wouldn't it be slow to connect to the database every time if I have, e.g., a thousand user connections at the moment?

Comment: I always prefer to trust my DB than the details sent from the client. And with a proper indexed table, the query shouldn't take so long

Comment: "if I have, e.g., a thousand user connections at the moment" --- if you had a thousand simultaneous users - you would not ask such a trivial question.

Comment: @AlonEitan to prevent CSRF attacks one must use proper methods, instead of exposing the authentication token to potential XSS.

Comment: @zerkms My API also serves native mobile apps, so I decided that it will be easier to escape use input and use angularjs build in protection against xss (`ngBind`), sanitize user input on the server side as a protection against XSS, and not to use cookies